# Trying to proof NP-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Imagine I have an equation like

A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + … = Some Value

And every summand has an upper limit

A ≤ 500,
B ≤ 200,
C ≤ 300,
D ≤ 600,
…

If i want a program to determine every possible combination of the summands, would the problem be NP-complete?
How would the mathematical proof look like?

If not, how would an efficient algorithm for this problem look like?

Comment: This is weirdly phrased, the problem being in NPC or not has nothing to do with any implementation and it's not even clear what this problem is in the first place. It looks at first as if it's going to be some trivial decision problem, but then you talk about combinations..

Comment: Your problem is an alteration of the subset-sum problem, for which there are algorithms (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). It has already been proven that the subset sum problem is NP complete, so it should still be NP-complete if upper limits are imposed on the parameters. In fact it is, because wikipedia says so. (link above: "For the case that each xi (summand) is positive and bounded by a fixed constant C, Pisinger found a linear time algorithm having time complexity O(NC)")

Comment: Are you interested in number of combinations. or actual list of combinations?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt this isn't like subset sum at all, unless OP phrased it even weirder than I already thought he did. It looks to be just a plain old sum over a bunch of variables each with a range, you can solve it in linear time independent of the upper limits (just go through it and set them all to their max until you're near the target). So clearly not NPC.

Comment: @harold is right. First of all: you want all solutions, but np-completeness only tackle decision-problems... Second: you want all solutions, but there may be infinite many). Third: If we are talking about finding one solution: this a very natural problem expressable in linear programming wich is ∈ P! (assumption: A,B,... are continuous variables)

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether the problem is NP complete, you must first figure out if it is in NP. We need to create a decision question from the problem.

If you wanted to set a limit on the sum without actually having to determine all the combinations of the summands, the decision question could be: Are there limits for A, B, C... such that the sum is ≤ k? Then your certificate could be a set of limits on the summands.

Here, the decision question is unclear and a certificate cannot be verified. This problem, as it is phrased, is not in NP.